# Cross-platform fonts in WxWidgets GLCanvas

Tags: opengl, fonts, wxwidgets

I'm developing a cross-platform app w/ wxWidgets and opengl...

I'm not sure what the best way is to have fonts work in the glcanvas. I've tried using FTGL but I think the version included in Fedora 11 must be broken or something since I can't get the example code on the web site to compile. I could try using GLUT or SDL but I'm not sure I want to include those as dependencies...

EDIT: Turns out it's just a different version than the one that is documented on the web site and has a completely different API.

Even if I have a font library though, all the ones I've seen require a path to a font file, and I have no idea how to do that in a cross-platform manner.

Answer (score 0):

Transliterate [this tutorial](https://threadpitch.net/mirrors/dmedia-tutorials-textrendering1/) to C++ and [array-embed](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Embedding_PNG_Images#bin2c) a gzipped copy of the [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html).  [QuesoGLC](http://quesoglc.sourceforge.net/) might also be an option, but watch out for performance gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

All platforms deal with fonts differently. There is no cross platform way to find fonts on a system. Alternatives include...

- Package your fonts with your app so you know where they are.
- Convert the fonts to a binary blob and embed them in your app.
- Test for the OS and set the font path accordingly.